# macOS - How can I install a new MacTex (LaTeX) package (a folder containing .sty or .bib files) and use it?

Tags: latex

I have been struggling to install a new package and use it for TexShop.

What I have tried is searching for the folder path: /texmf/tex/latex

However, even when enabling to see hidden folders, such a folder does not exist on my system. I therefore went ahead and created the three folder manually. I then placed my folders containing the .sty or .bib files inside. This does not seem to be working because I still receive the error that LaTeX could not find the .sty file.

Another folder that I can find within my Library is not the texmf folder but a TeX folder (see screenshot below)

[image: contents of the folder TeX]

Do I maybe have to place the packages inside one of these folders instead?

Comment: What does `kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME'` say if you run it in the terminal?